# query length of nested lists

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to query following entries that have lists of lists and get their lengths:

Answer (score 1):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: '$molecules' },
  { $group: {
    _id: '$scene',
    molecules: { $push: { $size: '$molecules.data' } },
  } },
])
```

gives

```
{ _id: 7674, molecules: [ 2, 1 ] }
```